# JavaPoet - Field of type inner class

Tags: java, javapoet

I am trying to add an inner class (e.g. interface Listener{}) to a TypeSpec. Also I want to add a field of type Listener to my TypeSpec. How could i achieve something like that?

```
TypeSpec outerClass = ...;
TypeSpec innerClass = ...;
outerClass.addType(innerClass);
outerClass.addField(...); // How can i add a field of type innerClass?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’ll need to compute the fully-qualified name of the type. That’ll look like this:

```
ClassName outerName = ClassName.get("com.example.project", "Outer");
ClassName innerName = outerName.nestedClass("Inner");
```

Then you can call `outerClass.addField()` passing `innerName`.